# go.mod replace fails with "no required module provides package"

Tags: go

I have a question about using 'go mod edit -replace'.  I'm doing

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/.../jira.git
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira
cd -
cd jira
go mod edit -replace github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira=/tmp/go-jira
make
```

which results in

```
[localhost rhjira]$ make
GO111MODULE=on go build gitlab.com/.../jira
main.go:6:2: no required module provides package github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira; to add it:
    go get github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira
```

I've used 'replace' exactly this way previously without any issues.  Any one want to offer a newbie some advice on what I'm obviously doing wrong?  A diff of the go.mod file does indicate only that single change.

Comment: That repo does not contain a _package_ named `github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira`, and the module in the main branch of the repo you are cloning is `github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira/v2`. You need to checkout the correct branch or tag for the version you want cloned locally.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that already :(.  I backrev'd /tmp/go-jira to v1.16.0 (which is what is in the jira git repo's go.mod) and that also fails.

Comment: It appears you have not done that, or made a mistake somewhere. The procedure you shown here will work if the local copy is checked out at a compatible commit. See if `go mod tidy` gives you any useful feedback, or double check that there is actually a buildable package in `/tmp/go-jira`.